# Linear Representations of the Groups

Tags: reference-request, rt.representation-theory, books, textbook-recommendation

Does anyone know a good  book on Linear Representations of the finite Groups which does not assumes a lot of background. Book which will be good to study for computer science and will cover all( at least most) of the topics covered in Serre's book in first two parts.

Comment: Do you mean that Serre's (= J.-P. Serre) first two chapters assume a lot of background ? This is not my opinion, but you can guess that I am partial. Let me recall that JPS intended to write these chapters for chemists.

Comment: I agree with Denis Serre. You can hardly do better than J-P. Serre when he wrote this little gem. 

Comment: if you just want to do calculations with characters, and want something slower paced, then perhaps James and Liebeck's book would be suitable. I agree that Serre's book does not require much background, but it depends what you are after: are you looking for a book to study yourself, or to use while teaching a course, or ...?

Comment: Sorry, I mean first two parts.
The first part is written for chemists indeed does not assume any background. I am looking for book making the same way second part. 

Comment: Mostly I am looking for a book which makes second part in the Serre's book in the same way as a first part is done.

Comment: Have you tried Isaacs book?  I haven't looked at it closely, but it seems to cover many of the same topic's Serre does in Part II.  (BTW, Part I of Fulton and Harris is also an excellent reference for the basics of LRFG.)

Comment: Isaacs book is excellent if you have some background in group theory, but it does move fairly fast, so someone new to the theory might find it hard to read. The book by James and Liebeck is probably also my best guess at a book that assumes as little background as possible and goes forwards very slowly (and rarely requires the reader to fill out any sort of detail themselves)

Comment: Fulton-Harris, maybe

Comment: It would make it easy if you descrinbed the background you *can* assume and what you expect to get out of the book.

Comment: Of course I shouldn't sing my own praise, but the book "Elementary number theory, group theory and Ramanujan graphs" (by G. Davidoff, P. Sarnak and myself) has an introductory section on rep's of finite groups, which is directly applied to show that certain families of finite regular graphs are expanders. See http://books.google.fr/books?id=qSOqGs9FuHwC&pg=PA7&lpg=PA7&dq=davidoff+sarnak+valette&source=bl&ots=IZHQHNEXps&sig=Ol9rWUbaEnCHed-jy69uXPzgIFg&hl=fr&ei=-T8PTsHlBNHrsga66rn_Dg&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=6&ved=0CEEQ6AEwBQ#v=onepage&q&f=false